# how to call a function inside a function

Tags: php, function

how do i call a function inside a function?

here's my function.php

```
function query_user() {

$q_user = pg_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND     password='".$_SESSION['password']."'");

$r_user = pg_fetch_array($q_user, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);
$user_tblrows = pg_num_rows($q_user);

if ($user_tblrows==1) {
     $_SESSION['firstname'] = $r_user['firstname'];
     $_SESSION['lastname'] = $r_user['lastname'];

     function welcome_user() {
        echo $_SESSION['lastname'].', '.$_SESSION['firstname'];
    }
 }
```

in my seperate file i want to call the function welcome_user()

how would i do that? i am confused. i did this and i know it is not correct.

```
require 'function.php';
welcome_user();
```

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like functions, so I've put a function inside a function so you can call a function while you're calling a function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare your function earlier, but not inside another function. Then just call it inside:

```
function welcome_user() {
    echo $_SESSION['lastname'].', '.$_SESSION['firstname'];
}

function query_user() {

$q_user = pg_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND     password='".$_SESSION['password']."'");

$r_user = pg_fetch_array($q_user, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);
$user_tblrows = pg_num_rows($q_user);

if ($user_tblrows==1) {
     $_SESSION['firstname'] = $r_user['firstname'];
     $_SESSION['lastname'] = $r_user['lastname'];

     welcome_user(); //function call, not definition
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call it like this;

```
query_user().welcome_user();
```

Comment: Now that you learned how you can call it, you will come to enlightening realization that what you wanted to do is really, really, really, really dumb and you won't do it because it's troublesome to maintain such code.